# LCD display does not show any text (display lights + contrast adjusted)?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, lcd

I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 B +, plus an HD44780 2004 LCD display (4x20) and other small parts. But after I soldered my LCD to the I2C interface, GND to ground; VCC to 5V; SDA to SDA (GPIO 2); Connected SCL to SCL (GPIO 3), adjusted the contrast and wrote a small script via C #, nothing appeared on the display.

At first I wanted to display the time, but only occasionally ° signs came up. By the way, I downloaded the Iot.Device.Bindings package in Visual Studio. When publishing, I set the script as the release, the target framework netcoreapp3.1 and the target runtime linux-arm. Of course, I have already downloaded the dotnet framework 3.1.100 on the Raspberry Pi.

```
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Device.I2c;
using System.Threading;
using Iot.Device.CharacterLcd;
using Iot.Device.Pcx857x;

namespace L2C
{
  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      using I2cDevice i2c = I2cDevice.Create(new I2cConnectionSettings(1, 0x27));
      using var driver = new Pcf8574(i2c);
      using var lcd = new Lcd2004(registerSelectPin: 0,
                  enablePin: 2,
                  dataPins: new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 },
                  backlightPin: 3,
                  backlightBrightness: 0.1f,
                  readWritePin: 1,
                  controller: new GpioController(PinNumberingScheme.Logical, driver));

      int _counter = 0;

      while (true)
      {
        lcd.Clear();
        lcd.Write(_counter.ToString());
        _counter++;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea what that is. Hope for quick and helpful answers.

regards
Nico

Comment: I can verify. your code works fine. Did you run the code as root?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution was that I found the contrast setting on the back of the display